# Mathematical Expression using NCalc

Tags: c#, ncalc

I am trying understand the expression library NCalc.

http://ncalc.codeplex.com

If I have a script as below,

```
SET A = CLOSE - OPEN;
SET B = A>0.5 AND CLOSE > HIGH 
If(HIGH > 5, ROC(CLOSE), B)
```

**CLOSE** is a  List of double,
**OPEN** is a List of double,
**HIGH** is a List of double

AND **ROC** is a custom function which takes any List of double as input parameter and returns a list as output.

Can someone advice me if I can use NCalc library to parse this script? I couldn't find any documentation at Codeplex website.

Is there any where I could obtain the help file or documentation for NCalc?

Thanks a million.

Comment: The five pages linked under 'For documentation' at that site appear to cover everything you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. first two will be very straightforward for third you will just have to create your custom IF and ROC function

Comment: Actually, "if(cond, trueexpression, falseexpression)" is already implemented.